# Touch device 'atmel-maxtouch' not working in Android Ice Cream Sandwich with Tegra 2

Tags: android, kernel, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, atmel, tegra

```
I/EventHub(  146): New device: id=3, fd=118, path='/dev/input/event1', name='atmel-maxtouch', classes=0x14, configuration='/system/usr/idc/atmel-maxtouch.idc', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false
I/InputReader(  146):   Touch device 'atmel-maxtouch' could not query the properties of its associated display 0.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
I/InputReader(  146): Device added: id=3, name='atmel-maxtouch', sources=0x00001002
I/InputReader(  146): Device added: id=2, name='gpio-keys', sources=0x00000101
I/InputReader(  146): Device added: id=1, name='tegra Wired Accessory Jack', sources=0x80000000
I/InputReader(  146): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  146): Device reconfigured: id=3, name='atmel-maxtouch', surface size is now 1280x800, mode is 1
```

I need build the kernel or modify idc device. Could also make the kernel backports from HC to ICS. How I can fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "idc device?" What is the current behavior of your device?

Comment: The output of "getevent -lp" and dmesg would be useful to answer this question. Sometimes the input name from the kernel driver doesn't match up to the IDC file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## English

See [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330162). The problem is with the Atmel controller and the ICS kernel.

Here is the link to the driver posted on Github:

https://github.com/atmel-maxtouch/linux

---

## Español

Mira [este post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330162), el problema es con el controlador de Atmel y el kernel de ICS.

Aqui esta el enlace al driver posteado en Github:

https://github.com/atmel-maxtouch/linux

Comment: Stack Overflow is English only.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Desafortunadamente, la majoria de las personas de esta communidad hablan Ingles; Entonces en el futuro, solamente da una repuesta si puedes en Ingles. Perdoname si me Español no es muy bueno. Gracias! :)